# Azure AD B2C Integrating with Restful API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

So, I followed the walkthrough as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom).

Here is the flow:

The user enters username/password on the SigInSignUp Policy page (provided by Azure AD B2C) and is redirected to the ASP.NET Web API which I wrote to check some business logic.

At this point, I would like to redirect to different URLs based on the flags that I return as part of output claim. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Interesting question... the redirect url comes from the client as an input parameter to B2C... wonder if you can override that?

Comment: Can you implement the redirection logic in the client application based on the issued claims?

Comment: @spottedmahn, yes, if i can find a way to override the redirect url in the Web API code, that would definitely accomplish what I need to do. Please let me know if you know of a way to do that.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett. Hi Chris, the client application you're referring to in this case is a Web API. Not sure if we can implement a redirection logic in it.

Comment: I noticed that one can setup multiple reply url's on the application you wan to run the custom policy. If I can achieve to programmatically select the reply url in the API code, that would also solve my problem. Do you think there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to redirect to different URLs based on the flags that I return as part of output claim.

register for `OnTicketReceived`

```
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents {OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceived };
});
```

Use the event handler to do something to the response, like redirect, or set a flag to be read later.

```
private Task OnTicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext context)
{
    // set a flag for later. Maybe middleware?
    context.HttpContext.Items["DoSomething"] = true;

    // Or just handle the response completely

    if(context.Principal.HasClaim(claim => ...predicate about the claim... ))
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Location", "http://wherever.you.want.com");
        // tell the OpenIdConnect middleware we got this
        context.HandleResponse();
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(nameof(OnTicketReceived));
    //context.Principal = TransformClaims(context, context.Principal);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```